# EditText input doesn't appear when I click in an edittextpreference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm using editTextPreference to implement a Setting Activity. My problem is that when I click in an EditTextPreference it displays a dialog with the preference title but not appear an edittext to write. 
I have searched for this problem but It seems it hasn't happened to anyone. Any help would be appreciated

I have this code :

```
@EActivity
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.settings_activity_menu)
public class ActivitySettings extends Activity
{

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // Display the fragment as the main content.
       getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new FragSettings_())
            .commit();
   }
}



@EFragment
public class FragSettings extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener 
{
    @App
    MyApplication app;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


    }

    @AfterViews
    void init()
    {
       EditTextPreference url =(EditTextPreference)findPreference(app.getResource(R.string.CONFIG_URL_SERVER));
        EditTextPreference user =(EditTextPreference)findPreference(app.getResource(R.string.CONFIG_USER_);

        if(url!=null)
            url.setSummary(app.getSettings().getSharedPreferences().getString(app.getResource(R.string.CONFIG_URL_SERVER), ""));

        if(user!=null)
            user.setSummary(app.getSettings().getSharedPreferences().getString(app.getResource(R.string.CONFIG_USER_), ""));

    }

   @Override
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       // Register as listener to validate settings values
       app.getSettings().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       // Remove listener
       app.getSettings().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        EditTextPreference connectionPref = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(key);

           // Set summary to be the user-description for the selected value
           connectionPref.setSummary(app.getSettings().getSharedPreferences().getString(key, ""));
    }


}
```

My preferences.xml, in these editTextPreference is where I have the problem, the input doesn't appear :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/settings_server">

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/CONFIG_USER_"
        android:title="@string/settings_user"/>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:key="@string/CONFIG_PASS_"
        android:title="@string/settings_password"/>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/CONFIG_URL_SERVER"
        android:title="@string/settings_url"/>

</PreferenceCategory>

<Preference
        android:key="@string/AREA"
        android:title="@string/settings_area"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: are You sure that Parameters.CONFIG_URL_SERVER and Parameters.CONFIG_USER_ gives You the correct keys?

Comment: Yes, I tried to change that using R.string, but the dialog still doesn't show the input box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I found what was happening. I wanted to use the same text style that I was using in all my application, so in ManifestFIle.xml I had this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".mobile.settings.ActivitySettings_"
        android:theme="@style/PreferenceActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"/>
```

Which refers to this style:

```
<style name="PreferenceActivity" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:editTextPreferenceStyle">@style/CodeFont</item>
    <item name="android:preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/CodeFont</item>
</style>

<style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
</style>
```

It seems that if I use editTextPreferenceStyle it makes disappear the box input. This is my solution:

```
<activity
        android:name=".mobile.settings.ActivitySettings_"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"/>
```

And to custom the edit text I use this http://secutyhf.org/wordpress/zeegers/2014/12/16/android-edittextpreference-style/

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EdittEXTsTYLE</item>
</style>

<style name="EdittEXTsTYLE" parent="android:Widget.EditText">

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I really not understand is Your Parameters, but let me suspect You are giving the correct references with these to the Preferences. But usually, You have to initialize them with the correct Object:

```
    Preference url =findPreference(Parameters.CONFIG_URL_SERVER);
    Preference user =findPreference(Parameters.CONFIG_USER_);
```

must be

```
    EditTextPreference url =(EditTextPreference)findPreference(Parameters.CONFIG_URL_SERVER);
    EditTextPreference user =(EditTextPreference)findPreference(Parameters.CONFIG_USER_);
```

And it´s better to set the keys inside Your xml layout as a reference to a string in strings.xml, for example:

```
 <EditTextPreference
    android:key="@string/user_pref_key"
    android:title="@string/settings_user"/>
```

### EDIT

Be sure to use the correct context. For this, You have to wait until the Activity is attached by Override onAttachActivity. Make a global Context:

```
  private Context mContext;

     @Override
      public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onAttach(activity);
          mContext=activity;
     }
```

Then You can refer it in Your PreferenceFragment.

```
  EditTextPreference url =(EditTextPreference)findPreference(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.user_pref_key));
```

Comment: I tried what your suggested but I still have the problem. Iits when I open the dialog when appears that problem.

Comment: maybe that´s a context Problem. I don´t know what You have done with "MyApplication" app. But to refer the Context You should better do it like in my edit.